# How to search for part of string but not complete string notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

Using Notepad++ I want to search within files for C:\test but exclude C:\testing - I believe this can be done in regex but not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\bC:\\test\b
```

Try this.This should do it for you.

`\b` is the word boundary.

`There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:

```
Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.`
```